# Ruby convert an Array to Hash values with specific keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

Is there a way to pull the values from an array and assign them each a unique key in Ruby?

I want to be able to turn this array:

```
["12", "21", "1985"]
```

Into this hash:

```
{:month => "12", :day => "21", :year => "1985"}
```

I would rather not assign each value individually, like this:

```
arr = ["12", "21", "1985"]
bday_hash = {:month => arr[0], :day => arr[1], :year => arr[2]}
```

Comment: `ary = ["12", "21", "1985"]; h = { month: ary[0], day: ary[1], year: ary[2] }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`#zip`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip)

```
your_array = ["12", "21", "1985"]
keys = ['month', 'day', 'year']
keys.zip(your_array).to_h
```

Comment: If using ruby version < 2.1, `to_h` is not supported. Use `Hash[keys.zip(values)]` as suggested by @MikDiet below.

Answer (score 8):

You can take array of keys, zip it with values and then convert to hash

```
keys = [:month, :day, :year]
values = ["12", "21", "1985"]
Hash[keys.zip(values)]
# => {:month=>"12", :day=>"21", :year=>"1985"}
```

Comment: Yep, you were right. Documentation says "object convertible to hash". Conversion is done via `.to_hash`, which on hashes just returns self. And I misread the code at first and thought the conversion is done via "key value pairs" route, which would involve one intermediate hash and one array. Still it's better to use literals in cases like that one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other ways to obtain the desired hash.

```
arr_values = ["12", "21", "1985"]
arr_keys   = [:month, :day, :year]

[arr_keys, arr_values].transpose.to_h
  #=> {:month=>"12", :day=>"21", :year=>"1985"}

arr_keys.each_index.with_object({}) { |i, h| h[arr_keys[i]] = arr_values[i] } 
  #=> {:month=>"12", :day=>"21", :year=>"1985"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a method to Array to facilitate this sort of conversion.

```
class Array

  def fold_into_hash(values)
    result = {}

    self.each_with_index do |key, index|
      result[key] = values[index]
    end

    result
  end

end

month_day_year = [:month, :day, :year]

#...

puts month_day_year.fold_into_hash(["12", "21", "1985"])
```

yields this result:

```
{:month=>"12", :day=>"21", :year=>"1985"}
```

Comment: While you _can_ do it this way, there's no reason to since `zip` and `to_h` or `Hash[]` will do it faster.

Comment: Yes, of course and answers with zip were posted. The goal is to present alternate ideas. All answers involve some level of design compromise.